# Stop thread in android

Tags: android

I have a thread:

```
handlerStoper.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            startTime.setText(""+count);
                            startTime.invalidate();
                            count++;
                            handlerStoper.postDelayed(this, 1000);

                        }
                    });
```

How can I stop this thread i  other place?

Comment: where is your thread?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I want to stop handler...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to remove all the callback from an handler you have to call:

```
handlerStoper.removeCallbacks(null);
```

with the argument `null`  all the Runnable will be removed. If you want to remove a specific runnable you have to provide as parameter the instance of the Runnable you want to remove.

`public final void removeCallbacks (Runnable r)`

Added in API level 1

Remove any pending posts of Runnable r that are in the message queue.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void run() {
startTime.setText(""+count);
startTime.invalidate();
count++;

if(flag){

                        handlerStoper.postDelayed(this, 1000);

     }
}
```

set the flag value to false when you want to stop the thread.

Answer (score 1):

Handler mhandler=new Handler();

Runnable r= new Runnable() {

```
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        startTime.setText(""+count);
                        startTime.invalidate();
                        count++;
                        mhandler.postDelayed(r, 1000);

                    }
                });
```

//when stop thread write

mhandler.removeCallbacks(r);

Answer (score 0):

`public final void removeCallbacks (Runnable r)`

Added in API level 1

Remove any pending posts of Runnable r that are in the message queue.

Use `removeCallbacks` as @blackbelt Sugested or  pass the runnable instance as param.

```
    handlerStoper.removeCallbacks(null);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: When you'll remove the callback while it'll be running it it'll add itselt to the handler once again?

Comment: @Secator i din't understand your comment clearly. when you want to sop the run you can  eg: `m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask)`